# Cannot find module:'@algolia/cache-common'"

Tags: javascript, npm, aws-lambda, node-modules, algolia

note (tl:dr): everything works locally but not in lambda.

I have a lambda function in AWS and when I run the server locally everything works perfectly, the usage of algolia is being made inside a service, which is in an endpoint inside my server.
I tried installing @algolia/cache-common and it didn't help either.
Every call that is made to the lambda crashes the entire app because of this error.
is there any way to fix it?
the error is the following:

```
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@algolia/cache-common'
    Require stack:
    /opt/nodejs/node_modules/algoliasearch/dist/algoliasearch.cjs.js
    /opt/nodejs/node_modules/algoliasearch/index.js
    /var/task/dist/api/v1/services/algolia.service.js 
    /var/task/dist/api/v1/handlers/jobs.handler.js
    /var/task/dist/api/v1/controllers/jobs.controller.js
    /var/task/dist/api/v1/v1.routes.js
    /var/task/dist/api/routes.js
    /var/task/dist/serverless.js
    /var/runtime/UserFunction.js
    /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@algolia/cache-common'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /opt/nodejs/node_modules/algoliasearch/dist/algoliasearch.cjs.js",
        "- /opt/nodejs/node_modules/algoliasearch/index.js",
        "- /var/task/dist/api/v1/services/algolia.service.js",
        "- /var/task/dist/api/v1/handlers/jobs.handler.js",
        "- /var/task/dist/api/v1/controllers/jobs.controller.js",
        "- /var/task/dist/api/v1/v1.routes.js",
        "- /var/task/dist/api/routes.js",
        "- /var/task/dist/serverless.js",
        "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.js",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:202:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
```

the way I use the algolia is like the following:

```
const applicationId: any = config.get("ALGOLIA.APPLICATION_ID");
const apiKey: any = config.get("ALGOLIA.ADMIN_API_KEY");
const client = algoliasearch(applicationId, apiKey);
const index = client.initIndex("my-actual-index");
```

my lambda structure is a lambda and 3 module layers, which worked for every library I used, but doesn't work for algolia in particular. when I watch the lambda's packages I can see algolia related packages

I tried installing the exact package(@algolia/cache-common) and it didn't do anything,
also tried instally @types/algolia and didn't work as well.

is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "install" dependencies like `@algolia/cache-common` you are installing them locally.

---

**Your installed dependencies are not automatically available on AWS Lambda. Like your application code, your dependencies need to be deployed as well.**

---

That's why it works on your local machine but not in Lambda.

You did not write anything on how you deploy your code. Tools like [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) or the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com) usually take care of not only deploying your application code but also it's dependencies.

So I imagine you are deploying by hand. That means that you most likely will have to also deploy your `node_modules` folder to AWS Lambda.

Your deployment ZIP archive should look like this:

```
node_modules/
index.js
```

The `node_modules` folder will have a lot of sub-folders etc and obviously, you can have more than one `.js` file. But for the purpose of this post we leave it at that.

Comment: My modules are also deployed with the entire app - I use plenty of  packages that aren't algolia , and I always did it by adding it to the package.json - but only with algolia specifically => it displays the error above .

Comment: Have you checked, if the dependency is actually deployed? You might have a `node_modules` folder, but for some reason the dependency is still missing. You provided little information about your deployment etc., so it is super hard to know what happens. But before this can go on, you need to make 100% sure that the dependency is actually deployed, because this is the most likely cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed, the problem was me splitting to layers, and skipping the first index in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. But it is absolutely fine to accept your own answer. This is allowed. So if you can, change the accepted answer to this answer ;)

Comment: @Jens I marked yours because it was what made me find the problem. I haven't deployed the node_modules correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely be helpful to see how you are building your service. Are the Algolia modules in your core service lambda or one of the layers? I don't know much about layers but I'm curious if you have the same issue if all dependencies are bundled into the service itself?

Comment: It's in one of the layers.
I can't bundle all of them because the weight exceeds the limit, sadly.